# Showing another Messages Content in a message

Tags: discord, discord.py

im Working on a Suggestion Command for my Discord.py Bot but i dont know how i can programm it, so the approve message shows the Content of the Suggestion. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I’m unsure where you want to send this suggestion. But if you want to you can send the suggestion to a channel of choice doing

```
await bot.get_channel(channel id).send(embed=embed)
```

This will retrieve a channel of your choice (as in you put in the selected channel ID, and then send the embed (if you are trying to send an embed) to the selected channel.